# how to write a regex that mathces "obj.xxx" and change it to "[del xxx]"

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode

how to write a regex that matches "del.xxx" and change it to "[del xxx]". while xxx can be anything ...

any idea ?

i want to change my property calls in XCode from obj.property to [obj property] through xcode find and replace..

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this? The two syntaxes are equivalent unless you're using an expression of type `id`.

Comment: Maybe, like me, he thinks the dot notation is an abomination.

Comment: And his screen name should be [g revolution]

Answer (score 2):

Search for :

`(del)\.(.{3})`

Replace with :

`[$1 $2]`

Comment: Be careful though.  Things like `foo.bar = baz;` are legal and should be translated to `[foo setBar: baz];`